# Dockerfile for Meteor 2.2 proyect

Tags: docker, meteor, continuous-integration, dockerfile, devops

I have been trying for almost 3 weeks to build and run a meteor app (bundle) using Docker, I have tried all the majors recommendations in Meteor forums, Stackoverflow and official documentarion with no success, first I tried to make the bundle and put inside the docker but have awful results, then I realized what I need to do is to make the bundle inside the docker and use a multistage Dockerfile, here is the one I am using right now:

```
FROM chneau/meteor:alpine as meteor

USER 0
RUN mkdir -p /build /app
RUN chown 1000 -R /build /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY --chown=1000:1000 ./app .
COPY --chown=1000:1000 ./app/packages.json ./packages/
RUN rm -rf node_modules/*
RUN rm -rf .meteor/local/*

USER 1000
RUN meteor update --packages-only
RUN meteor npm ci
RUN meteor build --architecture=os.linux.x86_64 --directory /build


FROM node:lts-alpine as mid

USER 0
RUN apk add --no-cache python make g++
RUN mkdir -p /app
RUN chown 1000 -R /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY --chown=1000:1000 --from=meteor /build/bundle .

USER 1000
WORKDIR /app/programs/server
RUN rm -rf node_modules
RUN rm -f package-lock.json
RUN npm i

FROM node:lts-alpine

USER 0
ENV TZ=America/Santiago
RUN apk add -U --no-cache tzdata && cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
RUN mkdir -p /app
RUN chown 1000 -R /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY --chown=1000:1000 --from=mid /app .

USER 1000
ENV LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
ENV ROOT_URL=http://localhost/
ENV MONGO_URL=mongodb://locahost:21027/meteor
ENV PORT=3000
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/local/bin/node", "/app/main.js" ]
```

if I build with `docker build -t my-image:v1 .` then run my app with `docker run -d --env-file .dockerenv --publish 0.0.0.0:3000:3000 --name my-bundle my-image:v1`  it exposes port:3000 but when I try to navigate with my browser to `http://127.0.0.1:3000` it redirects to `https://localhost`, if i do `docker exec -u 0 -it my-bundle sh`, then `apk add curl`, then `curl 127.0.0.1:3000` I can see the meteor app running inside docker.

Has anyone had this issue before, maybe I am missing some configuration? my bundle also works fine outside docker with `node main.js` in the bundle folder and can visit `http://127.0.0.1:3000` with my browser.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I solved with this thread 
https://forums.meteor.com/t/dockerfile-problem/56258/

Comment: Finally I disabled force-ssl package and it worked as a charm